# Obtaining a function pointer to a non static member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Suppose I have a class:

```
class A {
public:
    A(); 
    void myFunc();
};
```

Then at a different point in the program I create an instance of class A, and attempt to obtain a function pointer to `myFunc()`:

```
A* a = new A;

//ATTEMPTS AT RETRIVING FUNCTION POINTER FOR A::MYFUNC

std::function<void()> fnptr = a->myFunc;

std::function<void()> fnptr(std::bind(A::myFunc, &a);
```

But both of these attempts present the error "call to non static member function without object argument"

Perhaps both of these attempts are totally off the mark, but essentially im trying to obtain a function pointer to the `myFunc()` function in the specific instance of `a`. Any help on how to do so is appreciated :)

Comment: In `std::bind(A::myFunc, &a` `a` is already a pointer. No need for another level of indirection. Take a look at [Lambda Expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as a more efficient alternative to `bind`

Comment: `std::function<void()> fnptr = [a]{ a->myFunc(); };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following syntax:

```
std::function<void()> fnptr(std::bind(&A::myFunc, a));
```

You could also use a lambda expression like this:

```
auto fn = [a] { a->myFunc(); };
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5szsfY).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that lambda is a perfect implementation. Perhaps just one follow up: if I then want to pass that function pointer to a function ```fnPtrHandler```, what would the prototype for ```fnPtrHandler``` look like?

Comment: If you want to pass this to a function, then the signature would be `void f(void (A::*)());`. Of course, you could pass a `std::function<void()>` or just make `f` a template.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to obtain a function pointer to the `myFunc()` function

Obtaining a pointer to member function for `A::myFunc()` can be done:

```
void (A::*memFuncPtr)() = &A::myFunc;
```

or even better, taking advantage of `auto`:

```
auto memFuncPtr = &A::myFunc;
```

However, to dereference this pointer (i.e., to call the member function it points to), you will eventually need an `A` object. This object corresponds to the one the member function will be called on.

You can dereference the pointer to member function, `memFuncPtr`, either in combination with an `A` object and the `.*` operator:

```
A a;
a.*memFuncPtr();
```

or in combination with a pointer to an `A` object and the operator `->*`:

```
A *aPtr = new A();
aPtr->*memFuncPtr();
```

As a result, you would need to keep a reference to the object or a copy of it in order to create `std::function<void()>` out of this pointer to member function.

#### `std::invoke`

Since C++17, you can simply use the [`std::invoke()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) function template instead of `.*` / `->*`. It unifies the syntax for the two cases exposed above:

```
std::invoke(memFuncPtr, a);
std::invoke(memFuncPtr, aPtr);
```

Comment: Further reading for more tricks and tools when dealing with a raw function pointer: [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the link. I extended the answer for introducing `std::invoke`.